# Apache2 fail when migrating Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, apache2

I'm currently moving some wordpress sites from one server to another.

the first went fine but the second gives this error when trying to connect:

This site can’t be reached
[site].com refused to connect.
Search Google for juul
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

But the domain works fine, if I point it at another web root folder.

The apache error.log shows

[Wed Aug 29 17:41:59.591868 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24813] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

What could be wrong?

[Update]

Found when reloading, this error:

[Wed Aug 29 17:48:03.897531 2018] [:error] [pid 24883] [client 62.242.41.180:33248] PHP Warning:  Declaration of art_MenuWalker::start_lvl(&$output, $depth) should be compatible with Walker::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /var/www/[site].com/wp-content/themes/Tech0x2/core/navigation.php on line 0

Comment: Is it possible the theme files did not fully transfer? The second error there makes me think the theme navigation walker code is not working correctly, especially since it cites line 0 in the error.

Comment: I don't think its that file. It starts with <?php

Comment: Just swapped the theme and now it loads, don't know why though.

Comment: Maybe a PHP version issue? Make sure the two environments are running hte same versions of things